# QMessageBox don't display Unicode Char

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, qmessagebox

I have a strange issue with Qt 4.8.
I want display a QMessageBox with cyrillic char and I do this with:

```
 QMessageBox mb(messageTitle,messagetoDisplay,QMessageBox::Question,QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::Default,QMessageBox::No | QMessageBox::Escape,QMessageBox::NoButton,this);
```

where messageTitle and messagetoDisplay are QString filled with a function that get cyrillic string from a UTF-8 file where every line is something like
"latin string"="cyrillic string":

```
if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
  QTextStream in(&inputFile);
  in.setCodec("UTF-8");
  while (!in.atEnd())
  {
    QStringList line = in.readLine().split('=');
    qDebug()<<line<<origMsg;
    if((line.length()==2) && (QString::compare(origMsg,line.at(0)) == 0))
    {
      inputFile.close();
      QString returned = line.at(1);
      return returned.replace("\\n","\n");
    }
  }
  inputFile.close();
}
```

The issue is that if I compile and run on windows with mingw everything works well, but when I compile and run under Qt 4.8 embedded the message box will have the correct cyrillic title but text will not display any cyrillic char...

Any idea?

Thanks and Best Regards.

Comment: the 4.8 version is from 2011... Maybe first you should take a newer version (the current one is 5.8). Then maybe we can help you.

Comment: What is the OS and the graphical backend ?